For all $x,y,z$ real number, prove that $(x^2 + 3)(y^2 + 3)(z^2 + 3) \ge (xyz + x + y + z + 4)^2$
Here is my progress so far:
1.) Equality Intuition
By intuition, equality occurs when x=y=z=1.
2.) Simplify by Fixing
By setting y=z=1 , the inequality simplifies to:
$$ (x^2 + 3) 16 ≥ (2x + 6)^2 $$
$$ 12(x - 1)^2 ≥ 0 $$,
which is clearly true.
3.) Fix  and Analyze Further
Next, setting , the inequality expands to:
$$ (xy - x)^2 + (xy - y)^2 + (xy - 1)^2 + 10(x - 1)^2 + 10(y - 1)^2 - 10(x - 1)(y - 1) ≥ 0. $$
The term
$$ 10(x - 1)^2 + 10(y - 1)^2 - 10(x - 1)(y - 1) ≥ 0 $$
is true by the AM-GM inequality.
4.) Expand Back to Three Variables
When trying to expand back to three variables, difficulties arise, especially with factorization.
At this point, I am stuck with the factorization for the full three-variable case. A hint or further guidance on handling the expansion efficiently would be greatly appreciated.
Let me know if you need further clarification


Oh yea, my bad.

If you are ok with full expansion, then one way to go about this problem is to consider the expression as a quadratic in one of the variables and show that the leading coefficient is non-negative, while the discriminant is non-positive.

By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality $$ (xyz+x+y+z+4)^2 = \left[x\left(yz + 1 \right) + y + z + 4 \right]^2 \le \left(x^2 + 3 \right)\left[(yz + 1)^2 + \frac{(y+z+4)^2}{3} \right]$$
Then, it would be enough to show that to show that :
$$(yz + 1)^2 + \frac{(y+z+4)^2}{3} \le \left(y^2 + 3\right)\left(z^2 + 3\right)\iff
\frac{(y - z)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2}{6} \ge 0$$
And this holds for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}
$

Alternative solution.
Remark. Note that the expression is quadratic in $z$.
We can use the discriminant of quadratic function.
Let $A := (x^2 + 3)(y^2 + 3), B := xy + 1, C := x+y+4$. The desired inequality is written as
$A(z^2 + 3) \ge (Bz + C)^2,$
or
$$(A - B^2)z^2 - 2BCz + 3A - C^2\ge 0.$$
We have $A - B^2 = 3x^2-2xy+3y^2+8 > 0$.
It suffices to prove that the discriminant is $\le 0$, i.e.
$$4(A - B^2)(3A - C^2) - (2BC)^2 \ge 0,$$
or
$$4A(3A-3B^2-C^2) \ge 0,$$
or
$$3A - 3B^2 - C^2 \ge 0,$$
or
$$x^2-xy+y^2-x-y+1 \ge 0$$
which is true since $x^2-xy+y^2-x-y+1
= (x+y)^2 - 3xy - (x + y) + 1 \ge (x + y)^2 - 3(x+y)^2/4 - (x+y) + 1 = \frac14(x + y - 2)^2 \ge 0$.
We are done.
